# Memcached keys: some clarification needed

Tags: php, get, memcached, set

I have read numerous guides about Memcached, however, several things remain unclear to me:

1) I've seen many examples, looking more or less like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT `name` FROM `users` WHERE `id` = 1;";
$memcache->set(md5($sql), $sql, false, 60);
$memcache->get(md5($sql));
```

However, with my limited knowledge of Memcache, I see a serious flaw here: I can't use the same method to store data with `INSERT/UPDATE` requests as, technically, it would result in a different hash

As a solution I figured I could use something like this: creating a class/function that would do the following:

```
class db {
 function insert($sql, $ttl, $key) { // $key would be the name of the key I would manually generate for each query. To maintain uniqueness for each user where needed, could be user_id_keyname
  $memcache->set($key, $sql, false, $ttl);
  mysql_query($sql);
 }


function sel($sql, $ttl, $key) {
  if ($memcache->get($key)) then return $memcache->get($key);
  else {
   $memcache->set($key, $sql, false, $ttl);
   return mysql_query($sql);
  }
```

Could this be a proper approach to my problem? Would truly love to see any comments on the code.
     }
    }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you want to cache results of an `INSERT`/`UPDATE` query? There's nothing wrong to use the md5 hash of the `SELECT` query because you don't need any other information to uniquely identify the result set. You only want to cache results from `SELECT` queries so you don't have to retrieve the data from the database all the time. When you update the data, you don't want to loose it so you have to send the query to the database.

There's another problem in your examples. You don't actually store any query results in the cache. You only store the SQL query which is useless.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The reason why I want to store `INSERT/UPDATE` requests is simply keeping the cache up-to-date. In other words, regardless of whether the cache has expired or not, if the MySQL entry has been updated, the cache gets updated as well. I have fairly little knowledge about how memcache works so the guides I've read so far seem a bit too abstract for me to understand.

Comment: This isn't really what caching is designed to do: the whole idea is that you can re-use the output of, say, a SELECT query more than once. That is to say, caches are used to ensure your server doesn't have to run the same query twice. In your case, however, it does have to run the same query twice, because the output is supposed to be fresh. What you could do is invalidating any memcached keys which you know were affected by an `INSERT`/`UPDATE` query, which will mean your site will always get the freshest results possible. But doing that really means your site isn't too suitable for caching.

Comment: Why so? It would still use the cached results if the original entry wasn't updated. Besides, the **prime** reason I'm considering Memcache is that I use MySQL for its multilingualism (since as far as I understand, .PO files would load the entire site's strings whereas MySQL queries can do indexed searches)